# bash script to rename files based on a calculation

Tags: bash

I have a file system containing PNG images.  The layout of the filesystem is: `ZOOM/X/Y.png` where ZOOM, X, and Y are all integers.

I need to change the names of the PNG files.  Basically, I need to convert Y from its current value to 2^ZOOM-Y-1.  I've written a bash script to accomplish this task.  However, I suspect it can be optimized substantially.  (I also suspect that I may have been better off writing it in Perl, but that is another story.)

Here is the script.  Is this about as good as it gets?  Or can the performance be optimized?  Are there tools I can use that would profile the script for me and tell me where I'm spending all my execution time?

```
#!/bin/bash

tiles=`ls -d */*/*`

for oldPath in $tiles
do
   oldY=`basename -s .png $oldPath`
   zoomX=`dirname $oldPath`
   zoom=`echo $zoomX | sed 's#\([^\]\)/.*#\1#'`
   newY=`echo 2^$zoom-$oldY-1|bc`  
   mv ${zoomX}/${oldY}.png ${zoomX}/${newY}.png
done
```

Comment: I think I would have chosen variable names that matched your explanation.

Comment: Excellent point.  I've updated the script to have variable names that match my explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REWRITE due to misunderstanding of the formula and the updated var names. Still no subprocesses apart from `mv` and `ls`.

```
#!/bin/bash

tiles=`ls -d */*/*`

for thisPath in $tiles
do
   thisFile=${thisPath#*/*/}
   oldY=${thisFile%.png}
   zoomX=${thisPath%/*}
   zoom=${thisPath%/*/*}
   newY=$(((1<<zoom) - oldY - 1))
   mv ${zoomX}/${oldY}.png ${zoomX}/${newY}.png
done
```

Comment: I think there's a small bug:  $zoom * $zoom is the same as $zoom ^ 2.  But what I need there is 2 ^ $zoom.

Comment: Ouch, reading comprehension :/ Sorry about that. In that case, `bc` is probably better, even though you can still make it pure `bash` with: `newTile=1; for ((i=0; i<zoom; i++)); do newTile=$((newTile * 2)); done`

Comment: Scratch that, I just noticed it's powers of 2, and `bash` has the bit-shift operator. :)

Comment: Awesome!  One more minor optimization, cribbed from the answer by "user unknown":  It appears to me, at least on my Mac, that this line works just fine: `newTile=$((2**$zoom-$thisTile-1))`

Comment: Ooh, bit-shift.  Even fancier!  I do think 2**$zoom is clearer, but hey, they both work, and I'd have to guess the bit shifting might have marginally better performance.  Awesome and thanks!

Comment: I did some very rough benchmarking and the above script is orders of magnitude faster than my original.  It takes less than half a second to run on a sample that takes my original script more than 10 seconds.

Comment: I'd like to include this script as part of a small toolkit.  I'd like to give credit.  If you could either leave a comment here telling me how you'd like to be credited or send me an email (rtrott@gmail.com), that would be great.  (Sorry for leaving this in a comment, but SO doesn't apparently allow private messaging.)

Comment: Heh, don't worry about it. If you really have to, just link StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

```
for oldpath in */*/*
do
    x=$(basename "$oldpath" .png)
    zoom_y=$(dirname "$oldpath")
    y=$(basename "$zoom_y")
    ozoom=$(dirname "$zoom_y")
    nzoom=$(echo "2^$zoom-$y-1" | bc)
    mv "$oldpath" $nzoom/$y/$x.png
done
```

This avoids using `sed`.  I like `basename` and `dirname`.  However, you can also use bash (and Korn) shell notations such as:

```
y=${zoom_y#*/}
ozoom=${zoom_y%/*}
```

You might be able to do it all without invoking `basename` or `dirname` at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the overall throughput of your rename is limited by the filesystem.  Choosing the right filesystem and tuning it for this sort of operation would speed up the overall job much more than tweaking the script.

If you optimize the script you'll probably see less CPU consumed but the same total duration.  Since forking off the various subprocesses (`basename`, `dirname`, `sed`, `bc`) are probably more significant than the actual work you are probably right that a `perl` implementation would use less CPU because it can do all of those operations internally (including the `mv`).

Comment: `bash` can do all of those operations internally. It's just not as pretty as Perl. (Did I just say that? :D )

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 improvements I would do, if it was my script. Whether they have an huge impact - I don't think so.

But you should avoid as hell parsing the output of `ls`. Maybe this directory is very predictable, from the things found inside, but if I read your script correctly, you can use the globbing with for directly:

```
for thisPath in */*/*
```

repeatedly, $(cmd) is better than `cmd` with the deprecated backticks, which aren't nestable.

```
thisDir=$(dirname $thisPath)
```

arithmetic in bash directly:

```
newTile=$((2**$zoom-$thisTile-1))
```

as long as you don't need floating point, or output is getting too big.

I don't get the sed-part:

```
zoom=`echo $zoomX | sed 's#\([^\]\)/.*#\1#'`
```

Is there something missing after the backslash? A second one? You're searching for something which isn't a backslash, followed by a slash-something? Maybe it could be done purely in bash too.

Comment: +1 for exponents without calling bc.  Even if it turns out to be less efficient for some reason, I had no idea you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

one precept of computing credited to Donald Knuth is, "don't optimize too early."  Scripts run pretty fast and 'mv' operations(as long as they're not going across filesystems where you're really copying it to another disk and then deleting the file) are pretty fast as well, as all the filesystem has to do in most cases is just rename the file or change its parentage.
   Probably where it's spending most of its time is in that intial 'ls' operation.  I suspect you have ALOT of files.  There isn't much that can be done there.  Doing it another language like perl or python is going to face the same hurdle.  However you might be able to get more INTELLIGENCE and not limit yourself to 3 levels(*/*/*).

Comment: The OP stated his 3 levels are semantic - he's not dealing with all subfiles in a folder, but a specific folder structure, in which a rigid 3-level assumption makes sense.